# iOS 7 Pullable view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, view, pull

I'm looking into implementing a subview in a view controller that will sit as a bottom bar of the screen until the user holds down and pulls it up to the top of the window to cover the whole screen.

What Google Maps does in Android/iOS with clicking on a pin and pulling the bottom bar up to see details is exactly what I want to implement.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SmqWPFi.jpg]

Here's what I'm talking about. I'm not sure what the best way is to implement this. 
I can either have an animation that is hardcoded when the bar is clicked causing the view to expands up and cover 3/4 of the screen and anchors there and 1/4 of the screen will be a map and once the map is clicked will drop the view back down. Or have the user drag and pull up the view and pull it back dock to anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You should have look at demo code from following github link which have implemented pullable behaviour similar to the Notification Center in iOS:

https://github.com/crocodella/PullableView